# can not get the value from the angular form?

Tags: angular

[image]I am new in the field ,i make a form and on submit i print the object on console but we can not get the input values.

this is my form.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onsubmit(form:ElementRef){
  console.log(form);
  }
}
```

and this my html code

```
<div class="formcontainer">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onsubmit(formelement)" #formelement="ngForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" id="username" NgModule name="username"><br>
    <!-- <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" NgModule name="email"><br>
    <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter your mobile numberr" NgModule name="mobile-number"><br> -->
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: change ``NgModule `` to ``ngModel`` in your template

Comment: sorry bro but it's not working

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: no bro there is not any type of err

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In html , change `NgModule` to `ngModel` .

In TypeScript file, change `form:ElementRef` to `form:NgForm` which is imported from `@angular/forms`